# How to sign in to my Google acount to use Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I can't sign in to Play Store and download an app. It keeps saying "Authentication required. Please sign in to your Google Account".

Comment: Please avoid using leet language like 'sin' should be 'sign', 'sayin' should be 'saying', 'ur' should be 'your' and more in the question. Such words sometime infuriate people, at least it does to me. // 'sin' has an altogether [different meaning](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=meaning:sin).

Answer (score 2):

From the home screen of your phone:

1. Go to Menu
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Accounts
4. Go to Google
5. Click add account
6. Enter credentials and attempt to login

Let us know if this resolves your issue.